# Finding out if a tool is using internet connection

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, virtual-machine, network-connection

I am using a tool in the VM running Ubuntu, and I suspect this tool is using internet as part of its execution. Its documentation is quite awful to figure this out directly. Is it possible to turn off internet connection to VM (I have root previlages) but still be possible for me to have access to VM? If there is a better/other way to find this out, that will work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download wireshark and install it on your VM. Examine the packets being sent to and from your VM

Edit: If you need to run it from the command-line, there is a command-line version of Wireshark available.

```
sudo apt-get install tshark
```

You could then examine traffic by running the following command:

```
sudo tshark-i any
```

Comment: Since this VM is command line only, wireshark didn't work. I used _tcpdump_ instead.

Comment: Glad you came right. There is a terminal-based version of Wireshark called tshark that you could also have used.